# Question about localizations of discrete valuation rings.

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring. Then $R$ has only two prime ideals: $0$ and the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. It is said in Hartshorne, page 74, Example 2.3.2 that the localization of $R$ at $0$ is $K$, where $K$ is the field of fractions of $R$ and the localization of $R$ at $\mathfrak{m}$ is $R$. In the book, $0$ is denoted by $t_2$ ($t_2=0$ is open) and $\mathfrak{m}$ is denoted by $t_1$ ($t_1=\mathfrak{m}$ is closed).

But according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring) it seems that $R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is also $K$ since $R-\mathfrak{m}$ does not contain $0$.

I am confused. Could you explain this? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: A discrete valuation ring $R$ is local and so localizing at the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ just gives you back your ring again: you ***don't*** get the fraction field. I don't see from the wikipedia article that they claim that $R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is a field. Sure $R - \mathfrak{m}$ does not contain $0$ but why does this mean that $R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is a field? For example that $R =\Bbb{Z}$ and $\mathfrak{m} = (2)$. Then $R_{(2)}$ is all fractions whose denominator is ***not a multiple of $2$***. Now my question is: If this is a field then what is the inverse of $2$?

Comment: Any multiplicative set that you invert should not contain zero, or any zerodivisors, otherwise the localization is trivial. In this case, $R_{(0)}$ means invert everything except zero, while $R_{\mathfrak m}$ means invert everything except elements of $\mathfrak m$, which means not every element gets an inverse.

Comment: I looked rather quickly through the Wikipedia article, and, like user38268, I saw no claim that $R_{\mathfrak m}$ is $K$. The closest thing I found was that if you invert *all* of the non-zero-divisors (which would be all of $R-\{0\}$ in this case), then you get $K$.

Comment: @user38268, thank you very much.

Comment: @Andrew, thank you very much.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, thank you very much.