# Question about discrete valuation ring and locally ringed space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image] Even though I try to understand the [following example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477350/question-about-localizations-of-discrete-valuation-rings), I have been in limbo. This example shows that morphism of locally ringed space could be not induced the homomorphism of rings without the condition of a morphism of locally ringed space. There are two questions I do not precisely understand the above example.

> i) This morphism is
>   not induced by any homomorphism $R \to K$

I just guess that i) is true because of $Spec K \to t_{0}$ is not a morphism of locally ringed space (according to the following [pdf](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~jmckerna/Teaching/13-14/Autumn/203A/l_16.pdf) on example 16.6). Unfortunately, I do not know why this map is not a morphism of locally ringed space.

> ii) $f_p^{\sharp}: \mathcal{O}_{SpecR, f(p)} \to \mathcal{O}_{R,
> p} $ is not a homomorphism

If I believe the question i), the reason is  $f_p^{\sharp}$ is not a homomorphism, I cannot also show that why $f_p^{\sharp}$ is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding $i)$:
Ring homomorphisms induce morphisms of locally ringed spaces.

So if the given morphism is not a morphism of locally ringed spaces, it cannot be induced by a morphism of rings.

Not to actually see that the given morphism is not a morphism of locally ringed spaces, you just have to look at the induced maps on stalks - the only thing that could prohibit a morphism of ringed spaces to be a morphism of locally ringed spaces is the condition on stalks.

So you need that the map induced on stalks is a morphism of $\textit{local rings}$, i.e. you want that the morphism carries the unique maximal ideal of the domain into the unique maximal ideal of the codomain.

However, on stalks the given map just induces the natural inclusion $R \to K$ again; this inclusion is $\textbf{not}$ a morphism of local rings:
The unique maximal ideal of $K$ is given by $\{0\}$. So if the morphism were local, it would have to send the whole maximal ideal of $R$ into $\{0\}$, which it obviously does not.

I don't really understand question $ii)$. Could you maybe add relevant context that's missing?

Comment: Um... It is enough to see the answer of Question i) Then, is it right?: Since each stalk is isomorphic to the local ring,  $f_p^{\sharp}: \mathcal{O}_{SpecR, f(p)} \to \mathcal{O}_{R,p} $ as 2 : 1 map... (i.e its domain is {0}(zero ideal) , m (maximal ideal) and its codomain is {0} ). Since $\mathcal{O}_{SpecR, f(p)}$ is not an unique maximal ideal, $\mathcal{O}_{SpecR, f(p)}$ is not a local ringed space, hence $f_p^{\sharp}$ is not a morphism of local ringed space.