# Example for a morphism between ringed spaces that is not a morphism of locally ringed spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, affine-schemes

I know that morphisms between affine schemes are exactly the ring homomorphisms. But could you give an example for a morphism of ringed spaces between two affine schemes that is not a morphism of locally ringed spaces? Thank you!

Comment: There is an example in Hartshorne reproduced here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3589132/question-about-discrete-valuation-ring-and-locally-ringed-space); you take the spectrum of a DVR $R$ (which has 2 points, 1 generic + 1 closed); the inclusion of the generic point *is* a morphism of LRS, so we instead take the "wrong" map on the level of sets by sending the abstract generic point to the closed point. This induces the same ring map (the inclusion $R\subset K=\operatorname{Frac}(R)$), but the maximal ideal $(0)\subset K$ doesn't pull back to the unique maximal ideal of the DVR.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you!